# Browse multiple pages in WebView on menu selection

Tags: android, browser, menu, webview

Goooood Evening all. I have a webview that loads a specific webpage. The user can then select Menu and then navigate to TWO other designated pages. The problem is that the second two pages will not load at all. I can't understand why and would like some assistance. Thank you.

```
public class News extends Activity{
WebView mgebview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news);
mgebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mgebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mgebview.loadUrl("http://goo.gl/rQp3tF");

    mgebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


}   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.newschoices, menu);
  return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.bookmark:
        Intent addContact = new Intent(this, BookGoogle.class);
          startActivity(addContact);
          break;
    case R.id.dlrnews:
        //Intent dlr = new Intent (this, DlrNews.class);
        //startActivity(dlr);
        mgebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mgebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mgebview.loadUrl("www.racingblog.com");
        mgebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        break;
    case R.id.gtplanetnews:
        mgebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mgebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mgebview.loadUrl("www.gtplanet.new");
        mgebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because you are not returning a boolean! Try using this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.bookmark:
        Intent addContact = new Intent(this, BookGoogle.class);
          startActivity(addContact);
          return true;
          break;
    case R.id.dlrnews:
        mgebview.loadUrl("www.racingblog.com");
        return true;
        break;
    case R.id.gtplanetnews:
        mgebview.loadUrl("www.gtplanet.new");z
        return true;
        break;
    default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Returning true lets us "consume" it here.

As a reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29

Sample Activity I just created, it works using the nexus 7:

package com.example.test;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508436/browse-multiple-pages-in-webview-on-menu-selection/19508494#19508494");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Manifest make sure you add: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

R.layout.activity_main :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I copied in your code, removed the "Break;" as it was unnecessary after the return and i'm getting the same result...It is as if there is no connection

Comment: Are you using an emulator an an actual device?

Comment: Nexus 4. Inside the WebView it displays the same screen as it would if i were in airplane mode. Keep in mind, it displays the opening page, the originally loaded page correctly.

Comment: @TheRedStig Edit answer to accommodate. The above code works on the nexus 7. Also I would assume that you added proper internet permissions? Though it loads correctly the first time, android may be "funny" about that.

Comment: wait...now that i add the second source it's broken again..ugh...what am i missing...

Comment: Can you re-update your Activities code and then post your manifest and layout code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39701/discussion-between-horvste-and-theredstig)

Comment: Totally my sites, shortened them and boom. victory